# Select count where statement

Tags: mysql, sql

Hello I got some troubles to counting count(where return = 0) in my sql code.

```
SELECT `return` 
FROM  `numbers`
WHERE list_id IN (
  SELECT id from listy where listy.number = "900000335300000939680320"
)
```

Here is a example, how to count up `return = 0` using this exact query.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/49501f/2

Comment: Can you edit & add the output you actually want?

Comment: Alex, sadly I think I can't (well you can try to use the data I have, try it - I am not very good at sql, just know the basics )

Comment: Do you want one row containing the count of 0 or a row for the count of 0 and the count of 1?

Comment: The question Alex has, and I share (despite the folks below making the best guess they can), is that we really don't know what youa re trying to get from this query. Is it a sum(`return`) which would also be a count of records where `return` is equal to 0? Whats the output you want?

Comment: I want the count of 0's

Comment: Oh my bad it works adding at the end return 0, I thought it might get more complex. Thanks all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `COUNT()` in your query, of course, and add an `AND` to only look at rows where `return = 0`.

```
SELECT COUNT(`return` ) AS returncount
FROM  `numbers`
WHERE list_id IN (
  SELECT id from listy where listy.number = "900000335300000939680320"
) AND
`return` = 0
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT count(*) 
FROM  `numbers` 
WHERE list_id IN (SELECT id 
                  from listy 
                  where listy.number = "900000335300000939680320") 
                    AND `return` = 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `sum` with expression and it will be evaluated as boolean you can have you count on basis of your condition,Also use join instead of sub query,below query will give you the count for `return=0` and `return=1`

```
SELECT sum(`return`=0) count0,
sum(`return`=1) count1
FROM  `numbers`  n
join listy l on(n.list_id = l.id)
WHERE l.number = "900000335300000939680320"
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/49501f/11)

Answer (score 0):

Use `AND` clause after `WHERE` to narrow result (last line), than count it how many you got `SELECT COUNT()`:

```
SELECT COUNT(return)
FROM  numbers
WHERE list_id IN (
  SELECT id from listy where listy.number = "900000335300000939680320"
)
AND return = 0
```

Comment: return is a reserved word.

Answer (score 0):

this may help you :

```
SELECT `return`,count(*) FROM  `numbers` n join `listy` l
on n.list_id = l.id
where l.number = "900000335300000939680320" 
and n.return = 0
group by `return`
```

[sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/49501f/20)